# Hibernate ":" (Colon) paramater escape

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

My `createSQLQuery()` method uses a table  `Tables::IMS_EPISODE`  which has `:` character,
 This will be considered as a Paramater , which needs to be set 
 is there any way to escape this character so that it won't be considered as paramater?

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateQueryException:
Not all named parameters have been set:
```

this is the Exception i get.
can anyone help me out?
Thanks.
DB Used: SAP HANA

Comment: For example you could use HQL and in the @Table("Tables::IMS_EPISODE") annotation in the entity you could put the name you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `\\:`   for that purpose for each colon.